# Modifying LibGDX vector2's seems to do nothing

Tags: java, libgdx, vector

I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
Vector2 test = new Vector2().setLength(20).setAngleDeg(45);
```

But when I'm trying to print its contents (such as `test.len()` or `test.x`) it just outputs 0.
I've tried different variations, such as `test.set(test.setAngleDeg(x))` or simply `test.setAngleDeg(x)`, but these also seem to not work, I'm assuming there's something about the class I don't understand.

I'm sorry if it's common knowledge, I just had trouble finding an answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taking a look at the source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.java), we can see that:

- `setLength` scales the vector to the given length while preserving its angle. But if the vector was a zero vector, then it doesn't *have* an angle, and the method gives up and does nothing.
- `setAngle` keeps the vector's current length and changes only its angle.

So starting with a new default vector `(0, 0)`, calling `setLength` is a no-op, because it doesn't know what direction the vector should point — a zero vector doesn't point anywhere. So you still get a zero vector, and calling `setAngle` on it results in a zero vector again (length unchanged).

You really need to set both length and direction at once for this to be meaningful when starting with a zero vector, something like:

```java
public static Vector2 MakePolar(float angleDegrees, float length) {

    float radians = angleDegrees * MathUtils.degreesToRadians;
    return new Vector2(
           length * MathUtils.cos(radians), 
           length * MathUtils.sin(radians)
    );
}
```

You could also do it like this:

```
Vector2 test = new Vector2(length, 0).rotateDeg(angleDegrees);
```

(Though this will involve strictly more math ops than the all-in-one function above. `rotate` functions handle the case where the vector has non-zero values in both x and y components, so the added generality is a little redundant in this case if it doesn't get inlined to let the compiler eliminate the zero terms)

Comment: I see, thank you so much!